# (Python)How to merge 3 decreasing list into one decreasing list?

Tags: python, merge

Using Python, write a function, which takes three lists as input: left, middle and right. These lists will already have been sorted into decreasing order. Merge these three lists into one list, with elements sorted from largest to smallest. Return the resulting list. Not allowed to use `sort()`.

```py
def Merge3Way(left,middle,right):
    """Takes three lists that are sorted in decreasing order and merges them into
    one list ordered largest to smallest"""
    res = []
    while len(left) > 0 and len(right)> 0 and len(middle)>0:
        if left[0] > right[0] and  left[0] > middle[0]:
            res.append(left.pop(0))
        elif  middle[0] > right[0] and middle[0] > left[0]:
            res.append(middle.pop(0))
        else:
            res.append(right.pop(0))
    if left:
        res.extend(left)
    if middle:
        res.extend(middle)
    if right:
        res.extend(right)
    return res
```

This is the code that I have made.
But when the input is `[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]`, the result is not correct.

What’s the problem in my code? Or any other ways to make the function?

Comment: Your code stops merging once you've exhausted one of the three lists, so the remaining two lists aren't going to get merged correctly.  Restructure it so that it continues the loop until they're *all* empty, and just make your comparisons handle the case where a list is empty.  E.g. `if left and (not right or left[0] > right[0]) and (not middle or left[0] > middle[0]): ...`

Answer (score 1):

This should help you!

```
def Merge3Way(left, middle, right):
    """Takes three lists that are sorted in decreasing order and merges them into
    one list ordered largest to smallest"""

    # We get one big list, for example [1, 2] + [3, 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    L = left + middle + right

    result = []
    while len(L) > 0:
        el = L[0]
        # by default, we think that it should be inserted at the end of
        index = len(result)

        # if there is a smaller item in the list, then insert before it
        for k in range(len(result)):
            if el > result[k]:
                index = k
                break
        result.insert(index, el)
        del L[0]  
    return result

l1 = [3,2,1]
l2 = [6,5,4]
l3 = [9,8,7]

Merge3Way(l1, l2, l3)
# [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

did not initially see what was necessary in the order of decreasing =)

Comment: This isn't very helpful -- you don't explain how it works, and they pretty clearly aren't supposed to use external functions to complete this assignment.

Comment: And this function produces the wrong output

Answer (score 1):

Following code based upon:

- 1st merging left and right to get an intermediate result
- Next merging intermediate result with middle
- Avoid use of lst.pop(0) since this i an expensive operation i.e. O(len(lst))

**Code**

```
def Merge3Way(left,middle,right):
    """Takes three lists that are sorted in decreasing order and merges them into
    one list ordered largest to smallest"""
    # Step 1: Merge left & right
    res_1 = []
    left_ind, right_ind = 0, 0
    while left_ind < len(left) and right_ind < len(right):
        if left[left_ind] > right[right_ind]:
            res_1.append(left[left_ind])
            left_ind += 1
        else:
            res_1.append(right[right_ind])
            right_ind += 1
            
    for left_ind in range(left_ind, len(left)):
        res_1.append(left[left_ind])
    for right_ind in range(right_ind, len(right)):
        res_1.append(left[right_index])  
                             
    # Step 2: Merge intermediate result and middle
    res_2 = []
    res_ind, middle_ind = 0, 0    
    while res_ind < len(res_1) and middle_ind < len(middle):
        if res_1[res_ind] > middle[middle_ind]:
            res_2.append(res_1[res_ind])
            res_ind += 1
        else:
            res_2.append(middle[middle_ind])
            middle_ind += 1
                             
    for res_ind in range(res_ind, len(res_1)):
        res_2.append(res_1[res_ind])
    for middle_index in range(middle_ind, len(middle)):
        res_2.append(middle[middle_ind])
                              
    return res_2
```

**Test**

```
result = Merge3Way([3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7])
print(result)
# Output: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dict to manage dups and take the repetitive `max` of the keys:

```
def merge(l,m,r):
    rtr=[]
    cnt={}
    # first count the entries in all three lists as merged:
    for x in l+m+r:
        cnt[x]=cnt.get(x,0)+1
    
    # now take the max of those entries and delete one by one
    # exit when all entries of cnt have been used
    while cnt:
        x=max(cnt.keys())
        if cnt[x]>1:
            cnt[x]=cnt[x]-1
        else:
            del cnt[x]
        rtr.append(x)
        
    return rtr
```

Test it:

```
>>> merge([3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7])  
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

>>> merge([3,2,1],[6,5,3],[9,8,7])
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

This method handles lists that are not the same length as well:

```
>>> merge([3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7,5,0])  
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Or if the sublists are not sorted at all:

```
>>> merge([3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7])
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The statement that each of the three list is already sorted is somewhat misleading; you still have to reorder the entire merged list since the lists may have duplicates or interweaving values. It is faster and easier to ignore the sorting of the three lists and just concentrate on the most efficient way to order the combination of the three.